# MySQL returns only first line when querying for MAX() and all names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
students:
name:     semester:
AAAA      1
BBBB      2
CCCC      3
DDDD      4
```

Where students is the name of the table and name & semester are the colums.

I want to select all the names and the max number of semesters.
Therefore I use the following SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT MAX(semester), name FROM students;
```

As result I get the correct maximum number of semesters, but only the first name.

Why does it only return one name and why the first of the table (and not the one with max semesters)?

I'm not interested in how to fix this but in why it behaves like this.

I'm using MariaDB 10.4.11.

Comment: This query shouldn't have run.  How could this query make sense?

Comment: It's `MySQL`.  No wonder.  No other dbms system will run this, not even MySQL 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like this because you are using an older version of MySQL that allows malformed queries.

Why is the query malformed?  You have an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`, so it returns one row.  But, `name` is not aggregated -- and presumably you have multiple names in the database.

MySQL used to support this syntax wholeheartedly but returns an *arbitrary* value of `name`.  Now it requires that you set a configuration parameter in order to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `GROUP BY` to group each name.  Otherwise it will aggregate the whole table, which of course only return one row.

```
SELECT MAX(semester), name 
FROM students
GROUP BY name;
```